# How can I code a timer to run simultaneously with my code?

Tags: python, countdowntimer

```
import time
import threading
import random
#declare variables and constant
guessingelement = ["Hydrogen", "Magnesium", "Cobalt", "Mercury", "Aluminium", "Uranium", "Antimony"]
nicephrases = ["Nice job", "Marvellous", "Wonderful", "Bingo", "Dynamite"]
wronganswers = ["Wrong answer...", "Nope", "Try again next time.", "Wrong answer. Nice effort"]
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False
guess_no = 0
score = 0
def countdown():
      global my_timer

      my_timer = 5


 for i in range(7):
     randomelement = random.choice(guessingelement)
     guessingelement.remove(randomelement)
     time.sleep(1)

    for x in range(5):
      my_timer = my_timer - 1
      time.sleep(1)
    print("Out of time.Haiya!")

countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target = countdown)
countdown_thread.start()

while my_timer > 0:

    #tips of the element
      if randomelement == "Hydrogen" and not out_of_guesses:
         print("Tip 1: It is the most flammable of all the known substances.")
         print("Tip 2: It reacts with oxides and chlorides of many metals, like copper, lead, mercury, to produce free metals.")
         print("Tip 3: It reacts with oxygen to form water.")

        #test the number of tries so that it doesn't exceed 3 times if answer is wrong
         while guess != randomelement and not(out_of_guesses):
             if guess_count < guess_limit:
                 guess = input("Enter guess: ")
                 guess_count += 1
             else:
                 out_of_guesses = True

        #add score, praise when answer is correct and encourage when answer is wrong for 3 times
         if out_of_guesses:
             print(random.choice(wronganswers))
             print(f"{randomelement} was the element.")
         else:
             print(random.choice(nicephrases), ", YOU GET IT!")
             score = score + 1
 
        

        if randomelement == "Magnesium" and not out_of_guesses:
           print("Tip 1: It has the atomic number of 12.")
           print("Tip 2: It's oxide can be extracted into free metal through electrolysis.")
           print("Tip 3: It is a type of metal.")
```

procedure same as the first question. And so on with my questions.

However, it shows that my_timer variable is not defined. The process that I would want it to undergo is that it will countdown for 5 seconds for every questions, and when the timer reaches 0, it will print out of time and proceed to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've shown, you haven't assigned a value to `my_timer`.

`my_timer = 5`

By assigning the `global` within `countdown()` you've merely allowed `countdown` to change the value of `my_timer`.  You still need to assign a value.